# Mongoose fetch all key values from a collection and put into an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

How do I fetch all keys named 'username' and 'username' with 'password'(password hash) into two separate arrays?
What I've tried so far:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('./models/user.js');
// doesn't work!
const users = User.find().byName('username');
console.log(users);
```

My user.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    loginId: String,
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    eMail: String,
    password: String,
    active: Boolean

});
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

---

Update:
**Desired output:**
Array of users:

```
['bert', 'joe', 'john']
```

Array of users with passwords:

```
[ 'bert', 'bertpassword', 'joe', 'joespassword', 'john', 'johnspassword']
```

P.S Yes, this is a login system.

---

**Dummy user entry:**

```
{
    _id: "5dc16a477bfe45097018a074",
    loginId: "1",
    firstname: "Test",
    lastname: "Testeroni",
    eMail: "test@testeroni.test",
    password: "test",
    active: "true"
}
```

Comment: please attach a sample of desired output

Comment: My output array might not be optimal for my login system, I would be glad if you could specify the correct solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [Lodash flatten](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#flatten) at the result

```
npm i lodash --save
```

then

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const _ = require("lodash");

const User = mongoose.model(
    "user",
    new mongoose.Schema({
        loginId: String,
        firstname: String,
        lastname: String,
        eMail: String,
        password: String,
        active: Boolean
      })
  );

const db = mongoose.connection;

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/dbName", {
  useNewUrlParser: true
});

db.once("open", () => {
  User.find({}, { firstname: 1, password: 1 }, function(err, users) {
    const flattenUsers = _(users)
      .map(({ firstname, password }) => [firstname, password])
      .flatten()
      .value();
    console.log(flattenUsers);
  });
});
```

Comment: Remove `.toArray()`. Mongoose does not have `.toArray()` cursor method

Comment: Now I get `ReferenceError: _ is not defined`

Comment: you have to install the lodash npm , and require it `const _ = require("lodash")`

Comment: If I install lodash I get ```TypeError: Cannot destructure property `username` of 'undefined' or 'null'.```

Comment: I have pasted all the snippet